# Wordpress Plugin Licencing to Domains

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and two plugins.

First one is server, which is installed to my blog. I create users with username, password and domain. Second plugin is for clients in which clients login using their username and passwords then whenever they add a post, it is automatically added to my website.

In client plugin, I post data to server plugin. I want to prevent fake logins with valid username-passwords but from wrong domain.

Is there a way to do this? Note that clients can edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

if the clients can edit the source, they can remove any lock / licencing if they want. To prevent this use a php crypter like [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/products.php)

I would write the main plugin encrypted and let the user do some configuring in seperate files or wordpress itself.
if your script is encrypted, it is easy to communicate to your server. Just send some data with _SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] (the domain where the purchased client script is running) and check if the domain is in your db. if yes, send some encrypted "ok" back to the calling script.